# Radio Buttons Won't Align Left or Inline

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails form, and the radio buttons stubbornly remain center-aligned no matter how I try to arrange their CSS and classes. More importantly, I cannot get them to display inline with the button label. They display one line above the label. The label is aligned left.

The form:

```
<%= form_tag students_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>

  <%= radio_button_tag(:whichParam, "studentNum", :checked => true)  %>
  <%= label_tag(:studentNum, "Student Number") %>  
  <%= radio_button_tag(:whichParam, "last_name") %>
  <%= label_tag(:last_name, "Last Name") %>

  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>

<% end %>
```

For the CSS, I've tried

```
.radio {
    display: inline;
}

.label {
   display: inline;
}
```

I've also tried erasing all CSS that refers to radio buttons or labels.

My guess is that I must have another line somewhere in my CSS that is causing the buttons to display center. But I can't find any other sections that might be affecting this.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Have you tried using class: "radio-inline" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the label to display inline with the button you need to use the radio-inline class like this:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:whichParam, "last_name", class: 'radio-inline') %>
<%= label_tag(:studentNum, "Student Number") %>
```

Comment: That is what I needed. Weird that nothing about that came up while I was searching. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. That class took care of both problems. But I had to place the button_tag inside the label. Like this:    <label class="radio-inline">
    <%= radio_button_tag(:whichParam, "last_name", :class => 'radio-inline', checked: false) %> Last Name
  </label>